# Ethernet cord is plugged in but not connecting to the internet

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I just recently added Ubuntu 20.04 to an old desktop of mine. I have wi-fi on it working, but whenever I plug in the ethernet cord, it loads for a bit of time, and then says that the connection failed. I am new to linux, so I am not sure what I should do or add to this to make this easier to help me with. Could someone give me the walk-through of what to do, I'll show any results of commands.

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you connect the cable. Look at `service NetworkManager status`.

Comment: Suspected: Pins in connectors or wires in cables broken, such that "connector insertion" can be detected, but a connection cannot be made; e.g. a request can be made, but the response cannot be received.